# Vim regex for git merge conflicts

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Im making a plugin that will add syntax groups for files with merge conflicts in vim.

An example conflict is shown below.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
ourselves
=======
themselves
>>>>>>> deadbeef0123
```

The current regex for the `<<<<<<< HEAD` to `=======` is working correctly.

```
syntax region conflictHead containedin=ALL start=/^<<<<<<< \@=/ end=/^=\@=/
```

But Im stuck trying to get the right regex for everything *after* `=======`

```
syntax region conflictMerge containedin=ALL start=/^=======$\@<!/ end=/^>>>>>>> \@=/
```

[image]

The regex should get everything after the separator and up until the commit sha.

Any tips/pointers?

Comment: My [ConflictDetection plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4129) already implements this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command:

```
syn region conflictMerge containedin=ALL start=/^=======$\@<!/ end=/^>>>>>>> \@=/
```

Maybe you could replace the pattern:

```
^=======$\@<!
```

With:

```
^=======\zs$
```

On my machine, it seems to do what you want, that is highlighting the text after `=======` until the next `>>>>>>>`.

If it works and you want to better understand `\zs`, see `:h \zs`. Basically, it excludes everything before from the match, and uses it as a positive assertion (what is before must be present before the match in which you're really interested).

Comment: Hmm, it's not highlighting for me. Do you have a screenshot of what it looks like to you?

Comment: @mhartington Ah sorry about that. If I misunderstood the question, I'll delete the answer. Here's a gif showing the highlighting: https://imgur.com/a/cEEkF

Comment: Hmm, thats what I want, but for some reason, it's not highlighting the conflictMerge group. Tried in both vim and neovim

Comment: Wait, I was in a JS file, which was overriding the syntax, causing it to fail. Testing in a plain text file it works as expected.